# How can I stop datatables columns from being responsive?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [this template](https://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/examples/tables/datatables.net.html) from Creative-Tim.com.

Here is a link to the file:  drive.google.com/open?id=1EPLpOmM9bNj2-HH-v9rF6HvSoNtTqJtQ

The file is: BS3/examples/new_table.html.

I'm using datatables table and when the browswer window width is descrease, the column headers become responsive where longest table header names appear on top of the sorting arrow, which causes them to look staggered and crooked as not all of them do this because the header names are of different length. How can I keep them all static? I currently have the table set to `responsive = false`, and have a scrollX bar.

```
 var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
     "scrollX": true,
     orderCellsTop: true,
     fixedHeader: true,
     "pageLength": 10,
     responsive: false,
     sDom: 'lrtip'
 });
```

I just want there to be a decent space between columns and for them to stay that way and use scroll for when the page narrows.

Comment: does `responsive: false,` option not working for you?

Comment: it only works or the over all table, but not the columns

Comment: can you check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femjs7w1/), there is `responsive` option dropdown where you can enable/disable the option, if you have different behavior, I suspect that you have some CSS that overrides the expected behavior.

Comment: Well, I have 16 columns, which probably makes things more difficult. I would just the table header to stay at full width and use the scrollX bar when the screen is narrow.

Comment: Put that table in a div with a min-width that is just larger than the first responsive breakpoint, then overflow-x:scroll it. Or set a min-width to all columns, but then you'll still need the containing overflow div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then adding the following CSS will do the trick for you:

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    opacity: 0.8;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled  {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting.text-right,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc.text-right,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc.text-right,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled.text-right,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled.text-right  {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this does prevent the responsiveness of the headers, but the columns are now crooked. Is there any way I can send you the files? Its sort of impractical to write them up here. This solution is really close; I just need to allign the columns and space them out just a bit.

Comment: Maybe you could upload zip file to cloud storage like Google Drive and share the link here? But before doing so, let's try the edited answer first to see if it can solve the issue.

Comment: I actually tried this code myself; it didn't change anything. I just uploaded and shared the project. The file is: BS3/examples/new_table.html.        https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EPLpOmM9bNj2-HH-v9rF6HvSoNtTqJtQ

Comment: I just edited the answer, this might be what you needed.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change anything for me. The colulmn headers are still too close together with the <tr> columns a bit mal-aligned. I just want a decent space between columns with the headers staying still and not changing. Right now, the column headers are responsive, but the columns are mal-aligned and headers too close together.

Comment: Hi, I just found another solution, hopefully this is useful for you!

Comment: Sorry this is so late; but I tried your solution with the table being responsive, and you know what it happens to work out well that way for me. So thanks for the idea, you helped me alot, though it didn't exactly work 100% as non-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the template I can give you two hints:

- a header cell's width is calculated on the go by the plugin, is not rounded and set to something like "74.56px", so for some cells you get the calculated width smaller than it should actually be - the text and the `:after` don't fit.
- changing the font solves the issue

For a quick and dirty fix, and if you would like to keep everything else unchanged - consider change the font to something standard I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute;` is generally a bad idea in Datatables and any other plugin that resizes content automatically as it'll prevent them from being fully responsive, it might fix one issue but generates another.

The cleanest way would be to have a `white-space: nowrap;`. If it makes your headers too close to each other, just add a clean margin after each cell :

```
table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table.dataTable thead th::after, 
table.dataTable thead td::after,
table.dataTable tfoot th::after,  /* Don't also forget to give your footer the margin, to keep the header/footer properly aligned */
table.dataTable tfoot td::after {
    margin-right: 7px!important;
}
```

Note that this way you wouldn't disrupt the table's original layout by fixing values, this keeping Datatables free to resize the headers as it pleases afterwards. What's more important than just making it work, is making it work the cleaner way possible.

Otherwise, another extreme solution, that I once used in one of my projects, is to remove the sort icon definitively while still keeping the header sort, as when you have large header names it seems more convenient and most clients feel that it's already natural to click on the header to sort

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting::after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest fixed columns unless you have very certain criteria but what you are trying to is something like below:

Note that I added fixedColumns propertyand columnDefs property at the end of your dt settings.. Something like below should work:

```
 var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
     "scrollX": true,
     orderCellsTop: true,
     fixedHeader: true,
     "pageLength": 10,
     responsive: false,
     sDom: 'lrtip',
     columnDefs: [
            { width: 200, targets: 0 }, // add your column indexes for each specification
            { width: 150, targets: 1 },
            { width: 250, targets: 2 } // etc... 
        ],
     fixedColumns: true,
     scrollY:        "300px" // some certain scroll size if you need..
 });
```

And if that does not work, also try updating your css like below:

```
table{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; // ***********add this
  word-wrap:break-word; // ***********and this
}
```